# Why does a div with display:none break formatting?

Tags: html, css

The HTML code below consistently results in TEXT A and TEXTB not being horizontally aligned but removing `<div style="display:none;">&nbsp;</div>` fixes the alignment.  I discovered that using `div` elements instead of `p` elements fixing this issue, but am wondering what is actually going on.  I saw this behavior in in Opera, Firefox, IE (IE actually puts TEXTB on a separate line), and Chrome.

My expectation was that a div with `display:none` would not have any impact on formatting.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border-top-style: solid;">
            <p style="float:left; width:280px;">
                TEXT A<div style="display:none;">&nbsp;</div>
            </p>
            <p style="float:left;">
                TEXTB
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div` is not a valid child of `p`, so the browser applies error correction to the HTML to end up with this:

```
<div style="border-top-style: solid;">
    <p style="float:left; width:280px;">
        TEXT A</p><div style="display:none;">&nbsp;</div>
    <p></p>
    <p style="float:left;">
        TEXTB
    </p>
</div>
```

*(HTML taken from Chrome's Inspector)*

Note the extra `p` element.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can't put a 'div' inside a 'p'. So use a 'span' instead and see what happens